# Trouble Serving Django Static Files

Tags: python, django

I'm having a lot of difficulty serving static files using runserver.  I've included the configurations below, can someone help?

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Here is the top of my base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

What I have done so far:

I have already issued the 'python manage.py collectstatic' command, and only 'admin' static files where placed in the /staticfiles directory.  When running the command 'python manage.py findstatic css/style.css --verbosity 3' I get the following results:

> C:\Users\john.doe\Desktop\sysnet>python manage.py findstatic
>   css/style.css --verbosity 3 No matching file found for
>   'css/style.css'.
>
> Looking in the following locations:
>   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
>
> C:\Users\john.doe\Desktop\sysnet>

Why is it searching Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static ?  I'm guessing this is is why the collectstatic command did not place files from /static in the /staticfiles?

I have included the directory structure below (minus the files), can anybody help?

```
sysnet
├───.idea
├───chef
│   ├───migrations
│   └───templates
├───static
│   ├───css
│   ├───img
│   └───js
├───staticfiles
│   └───admin
│       ├───css
│       ├───fonts
│       ├───img
│       │   └───gis
│       └───js
│           ├───admin
│           └───vendor
│               ├───jquery
│               └───xregexp
└───sysnet
```

My style.css is in /static/css, and it should work.  The console output always shows 404 not found.

```
[29/Nov/2017 14:42:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3588
[29/Nov/2017 14:42:34] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1652
```

**I should note that everything works fine except for the static files.**

Answer (score 0):

The setting name is `STATICFILES_DIRS` (plural).

Answer (score 0):

Your STATICFILES_DIR is a tuple, it should be a list. You have it enclosed in parentheses whereas it should be this:

`STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]`